# What is the best Git workflow to use for an inexperienced team?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm a college student taking a software development course where we have to work in a team to develop a finished product. I'm working in a group with four other people to create a CRUD web application using CodeIgniter. They don't know much about source control, and none of them know how to use Git (which is what I decided would be the best VCS to use). They are all planning on using the GUI-based Github client to commit and push code.

What would be the best Git workflow to use in this situation? I originally thought about giving each of them their own personal branch to work on, along with a dev branch for testing changes and master for production-ready code. However after spending more time thinking about it, I think this might not be the best idea. I want them to be able to keep their local copy up to date as frequently as possible while also minimizing the number of merge conflicts that could potentially occur. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the `github flow` which is a very simple work flow.

https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

And the original post on the subject :
http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html

Answer (score 2):

If you use github then I would suggest:

- Create a user account for each user.
- Create an organization having all of you as users.
- Under the organization create the master repository
- Each user forks the master repository into their own account.
- On a regular basis, each user pulls the master repository to get updates.
- Each user creates pull requests when work has been completed, to go back into the master repository.

Comment: This would avoid a lot of branching and merging which is typical for teams working on a single repository.  The "pull request" approach moves the burden of merging to the commiter wanting to merge instead of the one receiving the merge.